# Line with a link is not shown in generated email

Tags: html, email, grails

My app needs to send a generated email when a user asks it. The email is sent with no problem (I am using Mail plugin, in Grails)but, inside there is a line with a link that is the purpose of the whole mail. But, it is not seen inside the email. The code is something like this:

```
'<head>'+
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'+
'</head>'+
    '<body>'+
        '<table width="690px" height="390px;" border="0px;font-family:verdana">'+
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+
'<p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 25px;text-align: left;">Blahblahblah this is the URL:</p>'+
        '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 25px;text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.myurl.com/promocion/verPromocion?promocion='+promocion.nombre+'&recomendador='+compradorInstance.id+'"> </a> </p>'+
        '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    </table>
'</body>'
```

I can see the <"p"> is drawn because there is an empty space where the link should be, but the link is not shown. Anybody knows why? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider using a multi-line string (with wither `'''` or `"""` rather than concatenating a bunch of strings together. Not only will it be faster, but it's also less likely to have syntax errors and will be a bit more readable. You can use the GString templating then as well if you use the triple double-quoted version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... Simply copy-pasted the url between the  and . This way:

```
'<p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 25px;text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.tikcode.com/promocion/verPromocion?promocion='+promocion.nombre+'&recomendador='+compradorInstance.id+'"> http://www.tikcode.com/promocion/verPromocion?promocion='+promocion.nombre+'&recomendador='+compradorInstance.id+'</a> </p>'+
```

And now it is shown properly.